# Get BBox of a GROUP of Raphael objects?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, vml

What's the best way to get the bounding box of several Raphael objects as a whole?

Can I put them all in a `set` and call `mySet.getBBox()`?

Or do I need to loop through them all, get `bbox` for each one and calculate the overall height and width?

(Also, I can't use SVG directly - I need VML support.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uh.  It's really easy.  (Thanks @Dylan):

```
var paper = Raphael ('test', 100, 100);

var circles = paper.set();

var c1 = paper.circle(70,30,10);
var c2 = paper.circle(50,10,10);
var c3 = paper.circle(10,80,10);

circles.push(c1, c2, c3);

alert(c3.getBBox().width); // --> 20

alert(circles.getBBox().width); // --> 80
```

Comment: Isn't that because you didn't push the c-objects in the circles-set ?

Comment: @Dylan - wow, my answer was painfully wrong.  Thanks for the tip - now updated in the answer.